# HTML - Change color of text depending on value with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I'm creating a table displayed in HTML with Django. I want to change the number's color to red when the number is negative, and to green when the number is positive. I know I need to use JS for this but I could not make it work. Any help will be greatly appreciated !!

Here is my Django HTML template :

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'WalletJournal/style.css' %}" />

<div id="container">
<h1>{{ Transaction.TransactionDateTime }}</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>TRANSACTION AMOUNT</th>
    <th>BALANCE AFTER TRANSACTION</th>
    <th>TRANSACTION COMMENT</th>    
    </tr><tr>
    <div id="TransactionAmount"><td style="font-family:'Arial',serif;font-size:10pt">{{ Transaction.TransactionAmount }}</td></div>
    <td style="font-family:'Arial',serif;font-size:10pt">{{ Transaction.BalanceAfterTransaction }}</td>
    <td style="color:white">{{ Transaction.TransactionComment }}</td>
    <script>
        var el = document.getElementById('TransactionAmount');
        if(el<0) {
            el.addClass += "red";
        } else {
            el.addClass += "green";
        }
    </script>    
    </tr>
</table>
<h2>Feel free to contact me !</h2>
</div>
```

And the classes I created in my CSS :

```
.red {
    color:#FF0000;
}

.green {
    color:#33FF3C;
}
```

I tried creating some JS code from examples I found around the web but something must be wrong. My goal is to check if the number TransactionAmount is negative or positive, and adjust the color accordingly. I made the TransactionAmount div to be able to use it with getElementById...

```
<script>
            var el = document.getElementById('TransactionAmount');
            if(el<0) {
                el.addClass += "red";
            } else {
                el.addClass += "green";
            }
        </script>
```

And my number is still gray....

Comment: `addClass` is a function, not a list. Try `addClass("classname")`.

Comment: Tried it but the numbers are still gray... Thx anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the `textContent` of the element to test it's value. And you can use a single class that toggles if it's positive or not. And either use jquery's `$.addClass()` and `$.removeClass()` or javascript's `classList.add()` and `classList.remove()`.

Also as Sujen K. pointed out, you have a `tr > div > td` for this element, and it should be `tr > td > div` instead.

```js
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('TransactionAmount');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  var cell = els[i];
  if (cell.textContent < 0) {
    cell.classList.remove('green')
  } else {
    cell.classList.add('green');
  }
}
```

```css
.TransactionAmount {
  color: #FF0000;
}

.TransactionAmount.green {
  color: #33FF3C;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>TRANSACTION AMOUNT</th>
    <th>BALANCE AFTER TRANSACTION</th>
    <th>TRANSACTION COMMENT</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-family:'Arial',serif;font-size:10pt"><div class="TransactionAmount">-1</div></td>
    <td style="font-family:'Arial',serif;font-size:10pt">{{ Transaction.BalanceAfterTransaction }}</td>
    <td style="color:white">{{ Transaction.TransactionComment }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-family:'Arial',serif;font-size:10pt"><div class="TransactionAmount">0</div></td>
    <td style="font-family:'Arial',serif;font-size:10pt">{{ Transaction.BalanceAfterTransaction }}</td>
    <td style="color:white">{{ Transaction.TransactionComment }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-family:'Arial',serif;font-size:10pt"><div class="TransactionAmount">1</div></td>
    <td style="font-family:'Arial',serif;font-size:10pt">{{ Transaction.BalanceAfterTransaction }}</td>
    <td style="color:white">{{ Transaction.TransactionComment }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I can see the snippet works but the text color still won't change on my webpage when I use your code... Maybe it has to do with where I put the JS script in my HTML...

Comment: @TajRaba you need to give us all of the info needed to make this change. From the code you provided, I gave you a working solution. If that doesn't work, then it's up to you to ask a better question and include all of the code needed to reproduce the behavior of the problem you're trying to solve. Otherwise, I would just be taking guesses as to why it doesn't work on your website, and that's a waste of yours and my time.

Comment: Hello again Micheal and thanks for your help. Sujen K found the other issue : it was a HTML hierarchy problem that was causing your solution not to apply properly in my webpage (you can refer to his post).

Comment: @TajRaba awesome! And I just tried it with your original HTML and you're right, it doesn't work. Sorry, I should have tried that first instead of telling you that you didn't give us all of the code needed to reproduce the problem.  Updating my answer with the full/corrected HTML.

Comment: In the end, it's not working... Your code just changes the first value in my list, it seemed correct at first but it's not when adding more values to my table. Looks like we're not using the correct value for our comparison (el.textContent > 0)

Comment: @TajRaba "Your code just changes the first value in my list" - what list? What do you mean "add more values" to your table?

Comment: @TajRaba I'm assuming you mean you have more than one of these in your table that you want to be green or red? If so, then `#TransactionAmount` needs to be a class instead. You can only have 1 ID on a page. And that changes the javascript, which needs to loop through all instances of that element on the page instead of using `getElementById()` which will only work with a single element since an ID can only be on a page once. Updated my answer. Let me know if that's what the problem was, and if not, I'll revert my answer back to what it was.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems. The HTML hierarchy should be **table > tr > td**, and you put **div > td**. The second problem is addClass. This is from the jQuery library, if you want to use plain JS its possible with className. Try this:

```
<div id="container">
<h1>{{ Transaction.TransactionDateTime }}</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>TRANSACTION AMOUNT</th>
    <th>BALANCE AFTER TRANSACTION</th>
    <th>TRANSACTION COMMENT</th>    
    </tr><tr>
    <td style="font-family:'Arial',serif;font-size:10pt"><div id="TransactionAmount">{{ Transaction.TransactionAmount }}</div></td>
    <td style="font-family:'Arial',serif;font-size:10pt">{{ Transaction.BalanceAfterTransaction }}</td>
    <td style="color:white">{{ Transaction.TransactionComment }}</td>
    <script>
        var el = document.getElementById('TransactionAmount');
        if(el<0) {
            el.className += "red";
        } else {
            el.className += "green";
        }
    </script>    
    </tr>
</table>
<h2>Feel free to contact me !</h2>
```

Comment: Hello Sujen, thx a lot you solved half the problem. Once I solved the HTML hierarchy problem, Micheal's solution worked.