# DJANGO - Change text color based on value (HTML & JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I'm creating a table displayed in HTML with Django. I want to change the number's color to red when the number is negative, and to green when the number is positive. I know I need to use JS for this but I could not make it work. Any help will be greatly appreciated !!

Here is my Django HTML template (linked to my view) :

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'WalletJournal/style.css' %}" />

<div id="container">
<h1>Transaction Journal</h1>
</div>

<div id="container">
{% if latest_transaction_list %}
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>From</th>
        <th>To</th> 
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Balance</th>
        <th>Date/Time</th>
        <th>Comment</th>
    </tr>
    {% for transaction in latest_transaction_list %}
        <tr>
            <td style="color:white">{{ transaction.TransactionFrom }}</td>
            <td style="color:white">{{ transaction.TransactionTo }}</td> 
            <td style="font-family:'Arial',serif;font-size:10pt"><div class="TransactionAmount">{{ transaction.TransactionAmount }}</div></td>
            <td style="font-family:'Arial',serif;font-size:10pt">{{ transaction.BalanceAfterTransaction }}</td>
            <td style="font-size:6pt"><a href="{% url 'WalletJournal:detail' transaction.id %}">{{ transaction.TransactionDateTime }}...</a></td>
            <td style="color:white">{{ transaction.TransactionComment }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
{% else %}
    <p>No transactions are available.</p>
{% endif %}
</div>

<script>
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName('TransactionAmount');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  var cell = els[i];
  if (cell.textContent < 0) {
    cell.classList.remove('green')
  } else {
    cell.classList.add('green');
  }
}
</script>
```

I know the JS code actually works since I got it from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42729608/html-change-color-of-text-depending-on-value-with-js/42729786?noredirect=1#comment72580895_42729786) and I tested it outside of my project. Unfortunately my numbers stay gray and don't change color. Even if I use a number like "1" or "-1" instead of {{ transaction.TransactionAmount }}, it still shows up in gray (I tried removing the gray basecolor from the CSS too but it didn't work).

Here's my CSS :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Eve;
    src: url('eve.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Retro;
    src: url('retro.ttf');
}  

body {
    background: white url("images/background.gif") no-repeat right bottom;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Eve;
    color: white;
    font-size:35pt;
    text-align:center;
}

h2 {
    font-family: Eve;
    color: white;
    font-size:20pt;
    text-align:center;
}

a:link {
    color:#008000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a:visited {
    color:#E09016;
    text-decoration:none;
}

table, td {
    font-family: Retro;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#3A5779;
    border-width:5px 5px 5px 13px;
    background:#1B2741;
    font-size:10pt;
    color:gray;
    padding:8px;
}

th {
    font-family: Eve;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#3A5779;
    border-width:5px 5px 5px 13px;
    background:#1B2741;
    font-size:14pt;
    color:white;
    padding:15px;
}

#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;
  text-align: center;
}

#TransactionAmount {
  color: #FF0000;
}

#TransactionAmount.green {
  color: #33FF3C;
}
```

And in case it can help, here's the model I use in Django:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Transaction(models.Model):
    TransactionAmount = models.FloatField("Amount", max_length=75)
    BalanceAfterTransaction = models.FloatField("Balance", max_length=75)
    TransactionDateTime = models.DateTimeField("Date & Time")
    TransactionComment = models.CharField("Comment", max_length=75)
    TransactionFrom = models.CharField("From", max_length=75)
    TransactionTo = models.CharField("To", max_length=75)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.TransactionComment
```

Keep in mind I have limited programming experience, and thx a lot for helping !

Comment: Put debugger in script tag, try to find the value of cell.textContent

Comment: Can you please get rid of most of that code and just share the bit you're interested in - this is not a good way to ask questions

Comment: Ids have to be unique (`id="container"`) and `TransactionAmount` is a class and not an id (`#TransactionAmount`, `#TransactionAmount.green`)

Comment: Well if I get rid of part of the code I'm afraid I'll remove what's actually causing the error.

Comment: I appreciate you already have the JS code, but do you need/want to do it in JS? It's much simpler to just do it in the Django template code.

Comment: I had to comment again, you really made my day @Whitnail !!! My code is a lot cleaner now with both the JS and inline styling removed :D ! THX THX THX THX

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I want to change the number's color to red when the number is negative, and to green when the number is positive. I know I need to use JS for this but I could not make it work.

You really don't need to do this in JS, so I've offered this as an alternative which both solves the original problem and simplifies your code.   If you have limited programming experience, you may be better taking the simpler route of managing this using the Django template, rather than a fairly lengthy JS solution.  Of course, if you want to fix the JS and use that because it's necessary for other reasons on your site, then the other answers will fix it.  :)

I've cut this down for the sake of readability as an answer. (It's also bad practice to have both a CSS file and styling inline!)

```
        <tr>
            <td>{{ transaction.TransactionFrom }}</td>
            <td>{{ transaction.TransactionTo }}</td> 
            <td>
                {% if transaction.TransactionAmount < 0 %}
                <div class="TransactionAmount NegativeTransaction"> 
                {% else %} 
                <div class="TransactionAmount PositiveTransaction">
                {% endif %}
                     {{ transaction.TransactionAmount }}
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>{{ transaction.BalanceAfterTransaction }}</td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'WalletJournal:detail' transaction.id %}">{{ transaction.TransactionDateTime }}...</a></td>
            <td>{{ transaction.TransactionComment }}</td>
        </tr>
```

And the appropriate CSS:

```
.NegativeTransaction {
  color: #FF0000;
}

.PositiveTransaction.green {
  color: #33FF3C;
}
```

Comment: This is indeed a lot better, I thought I couldn't do it without JS. Thx a lot :D

Answer (score 2):

In your html code you've defined 'TransactionAmount' as a class for your td elements, while in the css, you've defined rules considering 'TransactionAmount' as an id: `#TransactionAmount` and `#TransactionAmount.green`. So, changing the rules to `.TransactionAmount` and `.TransactionAmount.green` should fix your code.

Comment: You were exactly right, thanks a lot. In the end, Whitnail provided a much more efficient way to do this natively with django (see above).

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work fine when I tested it. I just had to add the `red` class.

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('TransactionAmount');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  var cell = els[i];
  if (cell.textContent < 0) {
    cell.classList.remove('green')
    cell.classList.add('red')
  } else {
    cell.classList.remove('red');
    cell.classList.add('green');
  }
}
```

Also, maybe you simply forgot your CSS for `.green` and `.red`, since it's not present in the CSS code you provided above.

**## Here, take a look at it in JSFiddle**

.

Comment: But only because you've fixed the wrong CSS rule where `TransactionAmount` is defined as an id instead of a class: `#TransactionAmount, #TransactionAmount.green` ;)

Comment: @Andreas I don't know what you mean. I did not touch any CSS code specifically for `#TransactionAmount`, since there is none to begin with.

Comment: Simple mistake on my part, I got confused when trying several solutions. It was indeed a simple CSS issue I solved by adding `.TransactionAmount {
  color: #FF0000;
}

.TransactionAmount.green {
  color: #33FF3C;
}` in my CSS (replacing the # with a dot)

Comment: In the end, @Whitnail provided a much better way to achieve the same result without using JS at all.